# Customizing the Bash prompt to include number of suspended processes

Tags: bash

I've read [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/) and would like to append to my prompt the number of processes I've currently suspended by pressing ctrl + z . According to that list I have to use the

```
\j
```

to be able to accomplish this. Ideally, I would like to append a

```
:(number)
```

to my prompt that would be red and bold if its greater than zero and regular and white if it was zero. If this "if"  behavior is not possible, then I could just have it always white and regular text. Could anyone help me out with this? Below is the output of my PS1 variable.

```
faramir@dev:~/testDir$ echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

Thanks!

Comment: Belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I didn't even know there was such a thing! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
PS1='...:\[$(((\j > 0))&&{ tput setaf 1;tput bold;})\]\j\[$(tput sgr0)\]...'
```

Comment: :o I don't even get it! I'll try it and then understand it after. Thanks!

Comment: I got a bunch of bash export not valid identifiers :l

Comment: Use single quotes, not double quotes.

Comment: *shrug* Works here. `[ivazquez@localhost ~]$ export PS1='\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w:\[$(((\j > 0))&&{ tput setaf 1;tput bold;})\]\j\[$(tput sgr0)\]\$ '`
`ivazquez@localhost:~:0$ `